# Does "significantly" also mean "clearly"?

Tags: meaning

> Application changes state significantly.

Does "significantly" mean "importantly"? Although there is no dictionary that states "significantly" means "clearly", I want to be sure if there is any chance that "significantly" might mean "clearly".

Regarding the source, I couldn't find it. I copied and pasted this sentence a long time ago. This sentence was found in an application manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that no, these words do not have the same meaning, even sometimes.

However, just because they don't mean the same thing doesn't mean that these things don't go together. It depends entirely on why the "change of state" in this application is significant. Generally speaking, a significant change is going to be easy to notice, and so the change will probably also be clear. Without access to the source or its context it's very hard to say whether a clear change was being implied or not.

Significant means important. Note-worthy. Impactful. When such things happen they are usually, but not always, also quite clear.